# AWS Cognito PreTokenGeneration appears to convert all types to string

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I created a lambda for PreTokenGeneration to add fields to all generated idTokens. It appears that all values get converted to string regardless of type. Is there a way around this?

Here is the lambda code as an example:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    // TODO implement
    event.response = {
        claimsOverrideDetails: {
          claimsToAddOrOverride: {
            someBool: false,
            someNumber: 123
          },
        },
      };
    callback(null, event)
};
```

Here is the decoded token body (I removed most of the irrelevant fields):

```
{
  "someNumber": "123",
  "email_verified": true,
  "someBool": "false",
  "token_use": "id",
  "auth_time": 1658949192
}
```

you can see that cognito does properly encode its native fields like `email_verified` and `auth_time`. Is there a way to make Cognito respect the requested types of non-native fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the AWS Cognito documentation, this is not possible.

As annoying as it is, this is behaving as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation.html#cognito-user-pools-lambda-trigger-syntax-pre-token-generation).

The response.claimsOverrideDetails.claimsToAddOrOverride where you correctly are adding the claims you want added to the jwt takes a StringMap type, which is an object with all key value pairs having all values being strings.

Even though some of the pre-existing claims created by AWS and passed into the lambda are key value pairs where the value is a `number` (eg `auth_time` in your question), AWS allows the lambda to only add string values.

You can find this on [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation.html) (find the text: `"claimsToAddOrOverride": {"string": "string"},`)